# How to update model value in android

Tags: android, models, parcelable, auto-value

I am using AutoValue in my models, I want to update the `isTrue()` value of the model when the user does something. So I need help. Here is my model.

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class Xyz implements Parcelable {

    @SerializedName("isTrue")
    public abstract boolean isTrue();

    @Nullable
    @SerializedName("lead_image_url")
    public abstract String lead_image_url();

    public static TypeAdapter<Readable> typeAdapter(Gson gson) {
        return new AutoValue_Readable.GsonTypeAdapter(gson);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use-case for `@AutoValue` is creating

> Generated immutable value classes ...

If you want to change a value, you'd have to create a new instance of the type, updating this one value.

This can be easily implemented with [auto-value-with](https://github.com/gabrielittner/auto-value-with). Just add a with-method to your type.

```
public abstract Xyz withIsTrue(boolean isTrue);
```

The extension will implement the method copying all data to the new instance.